# SVN and moving large files between projects

Tags: svn

Lets say I have project A on SVN server, and it has some large file.

Lets say I create a new project B, but it is actually a copy of project A. I create it, import it on the SVN server (different folder / URL), and I start with a new revision history.

The problem is, that new project has that same large file - can I somehow reuse that large file from project A, by perhaps moving it, so that I don't have to transfer it over the network? I want SVN to be able to say: "Oh, this is the same file, you don't need to commit that"

After everything, I want to delete project A.

Comment: Do you care if the large file's history is preserved?

Comment: What do you think should happen when the file is changed in project A, and changed differently in project B? Actually, this will result in 2 different large files!

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I create a new project B, but
>   it is actually a copy of project A.

```
svn cp http://path/to/repo/A/ http://path/to/repo/B/
```

This is actually what version control is all about. Subversion makes cheap copies, by just creating references, if the files are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to delete project "A" then you could use the large file as an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

It sounds like you don't want to move the file over the network, but you want to move it into another repository. So, do it all on your SVN server:

- Check out "A" and "B"
- Copy the large file into the "B" working directory,
- svn add
- svn ci

Done.